# Time complexity of two nested loops depending on n and k

Tags: time-complexity

I have a string of `n` chars and a `k` length of unique substrings

I'm trying to understand the time complexity of this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= inputStr.length() - k; i++) {
    String substr = inputStr.substring(i, i + k);
    Set<Character> setChars =  new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        setChars.add(substr.charAt(j));
    }
    if (setChars.size() == num) {
        set.add(substr);
    }
}
```

If I correctly understood the time complexity might be expressed by the formula:

> f((n-k+1)*k)

I believe that the worse case I can have is when `k = n/2`, so:

> f((n-k+1)*k) = n*n/2 - n/2*n/2 + n/2 = 1/2*n*n - 1/4*n*n + 1/2*n =>
>   O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct until the implication.

> f((n-k+1)k) = nn/2 - n/2*n/2 + n/2 = 1/2*n*n - 1/4*n*n + 1/2*n

= 1/4n*n + 1/2*n => O(n*n)

Comment: Oh, I applied the "ignore coefficients" rule too early. Thanks!